# what is wrong with my unpair implementation?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to figure out WHY i'm getting the error below more than I am interested in a correct implementation of my method.

I have the following f# code that is supposed to unpair a list of tuples into a list containing all the items in the tuples like so:

```
let unpair l =
    let rec loop acc l =
        match l with
        | [] -> acc
        | (x,y)::tl ->
            loop (acc @ x @ y) tl
    loop [] l

//should print:
// [1 2 3 4 5 6]

printf "["
List.iter (printf "%A") (unpair [(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6)])
printfn "]"
```

I get the following error for each of my ints when calling unpair:
This expression was expected to have type 'a list but here has type int

Why is it expecting 'a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the following expression

```
acc @ x @ y
```

The `@` is used to combine `list` values together yet here `x` and `y` are typed to `int`.  What you're looking for is the `::` operator which will add items to a list.  Additionally you are building up the list backwards in that expression.  Use the following and it should fix your issue

```
x :: y :: acc
```

Comment: so then is acc @ [x] the only way to append an item to a list, as opposed to x::acc for prepending?

Comment: @Charles essentially yes. Whenever you append to a `list` you're forced to create an entirely new `list` instance to do so.

Comment: Although `acc @ [x]` is the only way, you wouldn't typically write it (definitely not when you need to do it multiple times). It can be usually rewritten in a different (more efficient) way - e.g. using `List.rev`.

Answer (score 2):

As JaredPar explains, you need to use `x::acc` to add elements to the accumulator. If you want to append elements to the end, you could write `acc @ [x]`, but that's very inefficient, as it needs to copy the whole list for every single element.

The usual solution is to add elements to the front and then reverse the list at the end of the processing:

```
let unpair l =
    let rec loop acc l =
        match l with
        | [] -> List.rev acc     // NOTE: Reverse the list here
        | (x,y)::tl ->
            loop (y::x::acc) tl  // Add elements to the front  
    loop [] l
```

This is a lot more efficient than using `acc @ [x]`, because it keeps adding elements to the front (which takes just a small constant time) and then creates a single copy of the whole list at the end.

The same function can be also nicely & efficiently implemented using sequence expressions:

```
let unpair l =
  [ for x, y in l do
      yield x
      yield y ]
```

Comment: so your saying y x and acc all point to the same list (in different spots) when you use ::, but @ creates a new list?

Comment: When you use `x::acc` you create a single new node that contains `x` and points to `acc`. When you use `acc @ [x]`, the list `acc` cannot be modified (it is immutable), so it needs to be copied. You can try implementing `@` to see how it works.

Comment: @Charles Lambert: `@` operator creates a new list and is an O(n) operation defined somewhat like this: `let rec (@) a b = match a with [] -> b | x::xs -> x::(xs @ b)`. Prepending elements is cheap O(1), but appending items is O(n) which can degrade to O(n^2) if you append items in a loop.

Comment: You can also implement with non-tail recursive method: `let rec unpair = function [] -> [] | (x,y)::xs -> x::y::unpair xs`. Or with simple fold operation, `let unpair xs = List.foldBack (fun (x,y) acc -> x::y::acc) xs []`

Comment: That helps clear up a lot. Thanks. I've only been working with f# for a couple of days now. I've still got quite a bit to learn, but its starting to sink in now.